# How to save a TFilestream to hard drive with Lazarus

Tags: xml, save, filestream, xmldocument, lazarus

I am having a problem with saving an xml-file after changing some values. 
I use Lazarus 1.6 as IDE with FPC Version 3.0.0 
Here is the structure of my xml-file I use for this post:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <wbpickeys>
  <picture>
    <name>C:\IMG_1.JPG</name>
    <imagedate>p-06/04/2014 16:22:10</imagedate>
    <favorit>n</favorit>
    <remark>aaa</remark>
    <drive>DRIVE_FIXED</drive>
  </picture>
</wbpickeys>
```

I use the following uses clause (may be not all of them are necessary but I think at least the important once are available):

```
uses
Windows, ShellAPI, FileUtil, Graphics, Menus, ComCtrls, ExtCtrls, ExtDlgs, Classes, SysUtils, LResources, Forms, Controls, StdCtrls, Dialogs, CheckLst, Buttons, inifiles,
laz2_DOM, laz2_XMLRead, laz2_XMLWrite, laz2_XMLCfg, laz2_XMLUtils, laz_XMLStreaming;
```

On program start I load this xml-file into a Tfilestream (g_stream: TfileStream). The reason for that is to have an exclusive access during the program is running.
To achieve this I use the following open function:

```
function open_xml:Boolean;
begin
    if g_stream <> nil then FreeAndNil(g_stream);
    try
            //with load from (TFile)-Stream the xml file can be opened with Share Exclusive
            //when loading only from file there is no possibility to open it exclusive
            g_stream:= TFileStream.Create('wbpickeys.xml',fmShareExclusive);
            //Read the XML file into an XML Document
        readxmlfile(g_wbpickeys,g_stream);
            result:= true;
    except
        on E:EFOpenError do
        begin
             beep();
                MessageDlg
        (
          //br is defined as a constance for line feed
        '*** A T T E N T I O N ***' + br + br +
          'When trying to open the file for the keywords' + br +  '"wbpickeys.xml"' + br +
          'the following error occurs:' + br +
          E.Message + br +
          'Please check if the file is available' + br +
          'or deleted or moved or what else',mtError,[mbOK],0
        );
        result:= false;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Than I change the text value of one childnode:

```
procedure TForm1.BChangeNodeClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  pictures          : TDOMNodeList;
  pic, tempnode     : TDOMNode;
  i                 : integer;
begin
  // Get all nodes with name "picture"
  pictures:= g_wbpickeys.GetElementsByTagName('picture');
  // For all Member nodes
  for i:= 0 to pictures.Count - 1 do
  begin
    pic:= pictures[i];
    tempnode:= pic.FindNode('remark');
    // if content is 'bbb' change it
    if(tempnode.TextContent = 'bbb') then
    begin
      tempnode.TextContent:= 'aaa';
      //than I try to save the xmldocument to the hard drive    
      writeXMLFile(g_wbpickeys,'wbpickeys.xml');
    end;
end;
```

And here is my problem:
The new text is set and I am able to see the result in a memo. But the value has been changed only in the memory where the xml is loaded during run-time but not physically to the file on the hard drive. 
I looked nearly all over the net but I was not able to find a solution to save the stream to the corresponding file on the hard drive.

If I use this
“writeXMLFile(g_wbpickeys, ‘wbpickeys.xml’);”
I get an EFCreateError “Unable to create file wbpickeys.xml” in file lazutf8classes.pas line 143.

The problem is I do not want to create a xml-file – I want to change an existing one.

Than I looked for a possibility to save the stream to the file on the disk. Bur unfortunately I did not found anything for that.

For sure I make a mistake but I can not see it. Can someone let me know?

Comment: Create another file stream and copy to that stream

Answer (score 1):

When you write the modified document back to disk you must replace the entire file, you cannot restrict the operation to just the modified node. Therefore, you must first delete the old xml file (or better: rename it, just in case that something goes wrong during writing) and then write the document using WriteXMLFile. Or write to a new temporary filename in order to keep the original file locked all the time; then destroy the reading stream (to end exclusive access), delete the original file and rename the new file to the old one.

Comment: wow - thats sounds really complicated. Bevor I used Delphi and there is was much easier. But ok, many thanks for that response!

Comment: Complicated? I cannot imagine how to simplify this. And I cannot imagine how Delphi could have done it differently in principle.

Comment: I am not the real expert, but I guess with delphi and writeXML function there is not a creation of the xml but this function alters an existing file. May be the function did in the backround the same - delete the existing one and write a new one. But than this works without to let the user think about it. 
Anyway - I followed your suggestion and it worked. So many thanks
Andreas